# rqt_plot not plotting data

Tags: ros, ros-fuerte, tutorials, rqt-plot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Beginner Level Tutorial, 6. Understanding ROS Topics.
Examples work as expected until I get to 1.5 Using rqt-plot.
The graph shows up but I can't get data to plot (blank graph).
Tried all previous steps 4 times but still no plot with x:y or theta.
No errors are shown.
Reload doesn't help.
I'm using fuerte with ubuntu.
What can I try?
Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/59251/rqt_plot-not-plotting-data/) by [moallen](https://answers.ros.org/users/4528/moallen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2013-03-26

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Rebumble](https://answers.ros.org/users/4753/rebumble/) on 2013-04-24**:
I have this issue as well, using groovy in Ubuntu. Changing the topic name in the rqt_plot GUI doesn't change the graph, it stays blank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Make sure you running `turtlesim_node` running, in order for necessary topics (`/turtle1/pose/` in this case) to be published.

Btw however, I haven't been able either to specify topic `x:y` as an argument from commandline. You can work it around by giving the topic name on GUI's designated field.

Using `ros-fuerte-rqt amd64 0.1.6-s1360620793~precise`.

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2013-03-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Michele Palmia](https://answers.ros.org/users/4909/michele-palmia/) on 2013-05-16**:
I had the same problem and was not able to specify a topic from command line. Shouldn't this be changed in the tutorial?

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2013-05-16**:
I opened [an enhancement request](https://github.com/ros-visualization/rqt_common_plugins/issues/86). If you/someone could volunteer to modify the wiki I would appreciate it (right now I have no time to work on that).

**Comment by [Michele Palmia](https://answers.ros.org/users/4909/michele-palmia/) on 2013-05-17**:
I edited the wiki to reflect the actual use of the tool.

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2013-05-17**:
@Michele Palmia great!

**Comment by [TommyP](https://answers.ros.org/users/1110/tommyp/) on 2013-05-27**:
In groovy it works perfectly well to plot a pose with "rosrun rqt_plot rqt_plot /uav/0/pose/pose/position/x:y:z".  So what exactly is not working?

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2013-05-28**:
@TommyP what does this command return `dpkg -p ros-groovy-rqt-plot`?

**Comment by [TommyP](https://answers.ros.org/users/1110/tommyp/) on 2013-05-28**:
Version: 0.2.16-0precise-20130419-1956-+0000

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2013-08-07**:
@TommyP make sure the name of the topic is exactly the full name that's published. In your case do you see `/uav/0/pose/pose/position` is published (check by `rostopic list`)?

**Comment by [miloup](https://answers.ros.org/users/13906/miloup/) on 2014-03-26**:
I have the same problem. The plot window pops-up but no plot. My turtle keeps turning around... it is about to pass out, LOL I'm using the hydro version and unfortunately I couldn't figure out what the answer says. Please help!!

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is a way to get subplots working - not a very convenient one though. @dirk-thomas 's comment in this thread points in the right direction: https://github.com/ros-visualization/rqt_common_plugins/issues/86#issuecomment-21653925

You can load multiple plugins/instances of a plugin into the same rqt window. The command provided in the comment didn't work for me, but you can do it manually.

Start rqt

```
$ rqt
```

Then on the top left select `Plugins` -> `Visualization` -> `Plot` to add a rqt_plot. Repeat this to add more plots.

Note that every plot is independent. For example, if you pause one, the other continues to run.

This does the trick for me. Hope it helps you, too!

---

Originally posted by [bit-pirate](https://answers.ros.org/users/62/bit-pirate/) with karma: 2062 on 2014-08-08

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4